# Spring Test Kotlin Hamescreat has matcher

Tags: kotlin, spring-test

The jsonPath assertion in java:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/books")
                .content(bookInJson)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.timestamp", is(notNullValue())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is(400)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errors").isArray())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errors", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errors", hasItem("Author is not allowed.")))
```

Is failing to compile in kotlin equivalent:

```
mockMvc!!.perform(get("/api/customer/{id}", customer.id))
      .andExpect(status().isOk)
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", equalTo(customer.name)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.idNumber", equalTo(customer.idNumber)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.address", hasSize(0)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.contact", hasSize(0)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.address", hasItem("item")))
```

The hasSize assertion throws error: **Kotlin: Not enough information to infer type variable T**

How to perform a hasSize assertion in jsonPath with kotlin?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the type? e.g. `hasSize<String>(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @F43nd1r specifying the type works.

Code:

```
mockMvc!!.perform(get("/api/customer/{id}", customer.id))
      .andExpect(status().isOk)
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", equalTo(customer.name)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.idNumber", equalTo(customer.idNumber)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.address", hasSize<String>(0)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.contact", hasSize<String>(0)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.address", hasItem("item")))
```